# Pyinstaller app can't read but can write to files

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I made an app in Python 3 and when I "convert" it to an executable file it can no longer read from files. I assume there is a problem with reading files because writing works perfectly.
I tried both `--onedir` and `--onefile` modes, also adding files with `--add-data` and still nothing.

main.py file:

```
def write_to_file(content):
    with open('storage.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(content)

def read_from_file():
    with open('storage.txt', 'r') as f:
        f.read()
```

storage.txt file:

```
some text
```

My application saves the last state of `storage.txt` file before "converting" and it can read only the last state, any afterward changes are not readable (`storage.txt` file content changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this program work with pickle module as it was suggested in the comments by BoadGules. Thank you so much!

"Your program is storing the passwords as Python source code in `storage.py`. When you run `pyinstaller`, it converts that source code to bytecode, and that bytecode is what gets wrapped into the `.exe`. Any subsequent changes your program might make to the source of `storage.py` has no effect on the way the `.exe` behaves: your code remains frozen at the original version. That is just how it works. If you want to use `pyinstaller` then storing data as Python source is not a good solution. Have a look at the `pickle` module, which is most like what you are doing, or `configparser`."